# fitting iframe in columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 columns, the column on the left containing a form and the column on the right containing an iframe which shows a PDF file. I need the PDF as close to the left column as possible in order to fit them both on the page, although no matter what column sizes I use, the left column seems to push the right column out. Can anyone give me a solution to getting both columns side by side?

the edit view:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10" >

            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <h4>SecondarySchoolSurvey</h4>
                    <br />

                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RollNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RollNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RollNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfficialSchoolName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OfficialSchoolName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OfficialSchoolName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CampDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CampDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CampDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurveyFileName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SurveyFileName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SurveyFileName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FilePage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FilePage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FilePage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Q2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q4, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q4, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q4, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q5, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q5, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q5, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q6a, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Q6a, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q6a, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-2" >
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <iframe width="700" height="800" src="@Url.Action("OpenPDF", new { id = 8 })"></iframe>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is what they look like currently(if i make the left column size any less than 10 then the Labels start to shrink):

[image]

When I try both columns as col-md-6 this is what I get (if i make the left column size any less than 10 then the Labels start to shrink as you can see). I am not sure what is causing the white space in between the 2 columns:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the label in different column. Give label the enough space and reduced the first column width in two main columns (e.g 6 for form and 6 for pdf container). e.g

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" >
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried 6 and 6. the problem is the white space between the 2 columns, i have no idea what is causing it